# Bootstrap responsive tabs not working when window is not minimized

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, tabs

I used bootstrap responsive tabs, included everything that needs to be included. Tabs are working properly when i resize/minimize the window, but when the window is not minimized, they don't work.

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs responsive" id="myTab">
    <li class="active"><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#profile">Profile</a></li>
    <li><a href="#messages">Messages</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="tab-content responsive">
    <div class="tab-pane active" id="home">...content...</div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="profile">...content...</div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="messages">...content...</div>
</div>
```

Here is my code http://jsfiddle.net/rQZym/3/
Thanks!

Comment: Not minimized? That's the only time you can see anything.

Comment: Sorry, I am not so good with english, but i meant resized.

Comment: Ah. "Restored", in Windows parlance.

Comment: Ok restored, thank you.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what's not working. Your HTML shows tabs, but your JS converts it to an accordion. How is it supposed to behave?

Comment: They are working when they are on smaller window, but when you restore them to full width of a screen and click on tab, it is not changing.

Comment: I don't get tabs in your fiddle, even at larger sizes. The accordion works all the time.

Comment: http://prntscr.com/2xbn88 look here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The tabs received no click event.

```
        if ($this.parent().hasClass('active')) {
            active = ' in';
        }
        // Added click event for tabs.
        $this.click(function (e) {
          e.preventDefault();
          $this.tab('show');
       });
```

http://fiddle.jshell.net/y7TS5/3/
http://fiddle.jshell.net/y7TS5/3/show/